# What to use to fill mouse access point?

Tags: pest-control, mice

My wife and I have some field mice that have found refuge in our home through a gap between the foundation and the side of our house. We believe this point to be their only access, as they’ve made distinct paths through the yard leading to this gap, and lots of droppings immediately outside of it. There are no other signs of entry anywhere else.

We’re currently dealing with the mice via traditional spring traps with immediate success, and I plan to continue this treatment until we go about 48 hours with no sign of them (obviously, we wouldn’t want to trap them inside).

Once we’re in the clear, what can I use to block their entry to prevent others from moving in? Do I need to buy an entire bag of concrete and go through all of that hassle just to mend a very small hole, or is there an alternative that might be as effective?

Comment: Copper "wool" or mesh is sold for the purpose of plugging such holes. The mice cannot chew it and it doesn't corrode. https://www.amazon.com/Stuf-Fit-Copper-Mesh-Birds-Control/dp/B0001IMLTY

Comment: @JimStewart Excellent! Just what I was looking for. If you’d like to rephrase your comment as an answer, I’d be glad to accept it.

Comment: So tempting to dredge up survey pictures of "computer mouse connector plugs" over the years, but I'll be good.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Would have gotten a genuine laugh from me, hahha.

Comment: broken glass is cheap and long-lasting. works well for many varmints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copper "wool" or mesh is sold for the purpose of plugging such holes. The mice cannot chew it and it doesn't corrode, e.g., [https://www.amazon.com/Stuf-Fit-Copper-Mesh-Birds-Control/dp/B0001IMLTY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001IMLTY)

Comment: The easy way to install the mesh is to stuff it in the hole, then spray some expanding foam on it.  It'll glue the mesh in place and provide some bonus insulation.

Answer (score 0):

Cement will be the most permanent solution. I was surprised to find 10 pound bags available at my local home center (Lowes). While the cost per pound is higher than  typical bags it is cheaper than throwing away the 30 extra pounds.